# How to suppress ns(namespace) prefixes in emitted SOAP messages with axis2/eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis, soap-client

How do I suppress namespace (the usual ns1, ns2, etc.) prefixes in axis2 within Eclipse? These prefixes are emitted in the SOAP messages in my current implementation.

I know there's a -sp option for WSDL2Java, but since I'm using Eclipse i'm not sure how. On a related note how do you specify the commandline options for WSDL2java within Eclipse?

I've tried modifying my xsd files to include     elementFormDefault="unqualified"     but it seems to have no effect on the axis2 generated code.

I'm using Eclipse JUNO and axis2-1.6.2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to suppress namespaces?

Comment: I am trying to develop a client for a third party web service. That web service runs natively on a router and the bare bones XML parser there does not support name space prefixes. If I emit prefixes I get a fault response. I have manually removed the namespace prefixes from the client code, and that works fine. But there's a lot of messages to be handled and it's a pain to manually edit/comment out the namespace prefixes.

Comment: i've got your same problem and i can't find a solution on the web, have you solved?